# form validation message not showing while using ng-messages

Tags: angularjs

Form validation message not showing while using `ng-messages`

Specified required in my input field still its not working. required error is set in the form field still its not working. Here is my code:

```
<div class="m-t-xs" ng-messages="$ctrl.movedetails.cmndate.$error" ng-if="$ctrl.movedetails.$submitted">
    <small class="text-danger" ng-message="required">Please fill this field</small>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="m-t-xs" ng-messages="$ctrl.movedetails.cmndate.$error"   ng-if="$ctrl.movedetails.$submitted">
                      <small class="text-danger" ng-message="required"  >Please fill this field</small>
                  </div>

Comment: Provide a demo code on plunkr.com . We cant help unless we see some code. Once updated, point me in the comment section

Comment: Sounds silly but did you set the `required` attribute on that input?